# Find my display socket

Tags: x11, display, socket, container

I'm trying to find my display socket so I can pass it to a container. I expect it to either be in `/tmp/X11.unix` or `/run/user/xxxx/wayland-0`, but neither exist. I'm using KDE Plasma with X11.

Comment: Does it exist in the hidden path `/tmp/.X11-unix/` (eg: `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`)?

Comment: Yes. I hadn't thought to check that. However, that's empty.

Comment: I don't know if that means there is no X server (no X or Xorg process running) and it's a Wayland-only display, or if there's an X server with traditional unix socket disabled. Do you have such X process running? Does it run with additional options?

Comment: According to `$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`, it's X11. And I don't have any weird options as far as I know.

Comment: What I meant is can you run `ps -aeldf | grep '[/]X'` and provide the result?

Comment: 4 S root        2139    2137  0  80   0 - 16397 -      11:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/sddm/sddm-helper --socket /tmp/sddm-authf178a05b-ad5b-4ac1-bb00-da0f2f99d5b3 --id 1 --start /usr/bin/startplasma-steamos-oneshot --user deck --autologin --display-server /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -background none -seat seat0 -noreset -keeptty -novtswitch -verbose 3

Comment: 4 S deck        2148    2139  0  80   0 - 12940 -      11:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/sddm/sddm-helper-start-x11user /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -background none -seat seat0 -noreset -keeptty -novtswitch -verbose 3 /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsession "/usr/bin/startplasma-steamos-oneshot"

Comment: 4 S deck        2149    2148  4  80   0 - 316768 -     11:11 tty1     00:15:28 /usr/lib/Xorg -nolisten tcp -background none -seat seat0 -noreset -keeptty -novtswitch -verbose 3 -auth /run/user/1000/9618cdb2-287f-4aff-96e5-a4cf0f7b6328 -displayfd 12 vt1

Comment: Didn't help me sorry. Let's try something else. As root: `ss -xlnp src == 'unix:*/tmp/.X11-unix/*'` . If there's nothing here, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: At least the output is shorter. :)
ss -xlnp src == 'unix:*/tmp/.X11-unix/*'
Netid    State     Recv-Q    Send-Q            Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port   Process                           
u_str    LISTEN    0         4096         @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 28261                  * 0       users:(("Xorg",pid=2149,fd=5))   
u_str    LISTEN    0

That is weird. It says X0 is in /tmp/.X11-unit, but there's nothing there.

Comment: Did you cut the line? were there two lines with a different fd= or just one?

Comment: Two? Does it not show two? Huh. Sorry, the second line didn't copy.
u_str    LISTEN    0         4096          /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 28262                  * 0       users:(("Xorg",pid=2149,fd=6))

Comment: Some part of running `xhost + local:` or binding it with `systemd-nspawn --bind` is causing the sockets to "disappear. "Powering down" or killing the container does not restore them, nor does `xhost -`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact results seen in comments, the system might have switched to using abstract sockets only, or the unix socket file has been deleted, or the X server is itself running in an other mount namespace that would hide the socket in an alternate `/tmp` (like would some setup with systemd's `PrivateTmp=yes` do)  or any other similar thing. In any case, the classical unix socket can't be used (for the alternate `/tmp` in a mount namespace, it should be reachable, but not bind mountable for use in a container).

Here on a quite traditional X11 display I can compare between:

```
# ss -xlnp src == unix:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
Netid State  Recv-Q Send-Q      Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port Process 
u_str LISTEN 0      4096    /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 20428              * 0     users:(("Xorg",pid=1287,fd=8))
```

and:

```
# ss -xlnp src == unix:@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
Netid State  Recv-Q Send-Q      Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port Process 
u_str LISTEN 0      4096   @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 20427              * 0     users:(("Xorg",pid=1287,fd=7))
```

The same process is providing two methods using two different sockets types. The former is the classical unix socket with a filesystem presence as `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` while the latter is a [(Linux-specific) abstract unix socket](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/unix.7#Abstract_sockets) which has no filesystem presence. It's actually [network-namespace bound](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/network_namespaces.7#DESCRIPTION). That means it can't be made easily available in an other network-namespace such as in a container, but it can usually be proxied.

One can use a tool like [`socat`](https://manpages.debian.org/socat/socat.1#ABSTRACT) to relay from a classical unix socket to an abstract socket. For example this would give back such socket presence at its usual place:

```
socat unix-listen:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0,umask=000,fork abstract-connect:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

as long as adquate permissions are granted within X11 (eg: `xhost +si:localuser:someuser` with `someuser` the user running the `socat` process).

Once this `socat` command is running, one can again use the usual bind mount method provided by the container technology to have access to this socket within the container.

Else one could even imagine staying in the host network namespace (to have access to the abstract socket) and switching to the container's mount namespace to create a classical unix socket directly there, but if that's not the tool itself that switches, that means the command (such as `socat`) must be available in the container and chances are everything must be run (from the host) as root to get enough privileges.

For example with an LXC container named `somecontainer` that is already running and has the `socat` command installed within, one can run on the host:

As the user owning the X11 display:

```
xhost +si:localuser:root
```

As root:

```
nsenter -t $(lxc-info -Hp -n somecontainer) --mount -- sh -c 'mkdir -p -m 1777 /tmp/.X11-unix; exec socat unix-listen:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0,umask=000,fork abstract-connect:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0'
```

Note: Docker's equivalent of `lxc-info -Hp -n somecontainer` would be `docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' somecontainer`.

---

The same method would probably fail with a Wayland socket, because the Wayland protocol also passes file descriptors as side-channel data within the unix socket communication and `socat` doesn't know anything about this.

Comment: Thank you for all that effort, unfortunately (or fortunately), after a reboot, the sockets are showing where they are supposed to be. If this ever happens again, I'll be sure to try this, however.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. Sort of. I'll post in a comment on the question.